# Django NoReverseMatch at /search/

Tags: django, django-urls

In a search form, users can choose some of the criteria (country, province and city) and post it the result to this view:

```
def profile_search(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            country=cd['country']
            province=cd['province']
            city = cd['city']

            params=( country, province, city ,)


            url = reverse('userprofile.views.profile_search_result', args= params) 

            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)


    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/result/ایران")
```

Which is supposed to be found by one of these url patterns:

```
url(r'^result/(?P<country>\w+)/(?P<province>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)', 'userprofile.views.profile_search_result'),

url(r'^result/(?P<country>\w+)/$','userprofile.views.profile_search_result'),
```

However, no matter what criteria are chosen in the search form, I get  errors like:

```
Reverse for 'userprofile.views.profile_search_result' with arguments '(u'\u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0646', u'\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0632', u'')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['result/(?P<country>\\w+)/$', 'result/(?P<country>\\w+)/(?P<province>\\w+)/(?P<city>\\w+)']
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you pass 4 arguments instead of expected 3: `with arguments '(u062a', u'\u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u0646', u'', u''`. Try to print out `params` before you call `reverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

Firstly, `\w` does not match the Arabic characters you are using in your params - it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9]` only. You will need to explicitly use the Unicode codepoints for the characters you want to match, or alternatively a much more general `.`:

```
r'^result/(?P<country>.+)/(?P<province>.+)/(?P<city>.+)'
```

Secondly, in your pattern the city parameter is required, but you are passing an empty string. You should probably define a third pattern that omits that parameter:

```
r'^result/(?P<country>.+)/(?P<province>.+)'
```

But note that I don't recommend doing any of that. Rather than submitting your form as a POST and redirecting to a second view with URL parameters to actually do the search, you should simply use a GET action in your form and submit it straight to the search_result view, where you get the search query from `request.GET`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips Daniel. This solved my problem. As for your suggeston, I'm trying to use Post/Redirect/Get because  Is there any reason it is worse than getting data stright from request.GET? I don't know how to sanitize the form inputs if I use request.GET directly.

Comment: Please refer to the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939537/request-get-vs-request-post-redirect-get-vs-in-django

Answer (score 0):

try this line in urls.py

```
url(r'^result/(?P<country>.*)/$','userprofile.views.profile_search_result'),
```

this is sample of using unicode chars in my application:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('pin.views',
    url(r'^(?P<user_namefl>.*)/followers/$', 'absuser_followers', name='pin-absuser-followers'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_namefg>.*)/following/$', 'absuser_friends', name='pin-absuser-following'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_namel>.*)/likes/$', 'absuser_like', name='pin-absuser-like'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_name>.*)/$', 'absuser', name='pin-absuser'),
)
```

links from html pages

```
<a href="{% url "pin-absuser" username %}">
```

with reverse in views or models

```
reverse("pin-absuser", args=["وحید"])
```

Comment: The problem persists using this pattern.

Answer (score -2):

To use `reverse()`, you need to give the url a name, and use it in the reverse function - see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Example in urls.py:

```
url(r'^result/(?P<country>\w+)/(?P<province>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)', 'userprofile.views.profile_search_result', name='search_results'),
```

Example call:

```
url = reverse('search_results', args= params)
```

Comment: Right in the documentation you linked to, it explicitly says you can use the view directly (as a string path, or as a callable). You don't have to use a named URL.

Comment: It's certainly neater to use an explicit name, but it's not a requirement. And the error message clearly says the problem is with the arguments, not the name.

Comment: Correct - did not know this.