# request.GET vs request.POST/Redirect/GET in django

Tags: django, django-forms

In dealing with forms with multiple input parameters and pagination, where user can choose any number of parameters (like a search form) which approach is better and why? receiving data straight from request.GET in one view or implementing a Post/Redirect/Get (2 views).

using Post/Redirect/Get,  one can easily sanitize data using ModelForms builtin methods:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = MySearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        #do stuff with cd
```

How would you sanitize data using request.GET?

Why would you want to use request.GET instead of POST/Redirect/GET in such circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what your form does. If you're creating/modifying data, use POST. Otherwise, use GET (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

You can still use `form.cleaned_data` with GET, you just have to pass `request.GET` to the form.